# Helidon MP: How to disable the ssl validation?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, helidon

Currently, when my helidon application invoke a request to another server using https protocol, it will cause an exception about certification:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How can I disable this validation? Do the config "server.ssl.trustAll" or "server.trust-all" solve my issue?

The ssl validation should be resovled

Answer (score 0):

If you are Helidon WebClient you can do it like this:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                               .tls(WebClientTls.builder()
                                                .trustAll(true)
                                                .build())
                               .baseUri("https://self-signed-host.com")
                               .build();
```

You can do the same using configuration:

```
Config config = Config.create(ConfigSources.create(Map.of("tls.server.trust-all", "true")));
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                               .config(config)
                               .baseUri("https://self-signed-host.com")
                               .build();
```

If you are using JAXRS client, the default connector is based on HTTPURLConnection. You would have to setup your own SSLContext to perform the "trust" behavior:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                             .sslContext(/* ... */)
                             .build();
```